# Is there a way to programmatically tell if a system is touch enabled?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-7, touch

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically tell if a Windows 7 machine has touch enabled.  Are there any touch API's (managed or unmanaged) that can help me achieve this?  Or perhaps something in the registry I can check?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`GetSystemMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to look for `SM_MAXIMUMTOUCHES` settings.

> Nonzero if there are digitizers in the
>   system; otherwise, `0`.
>
> `SM_MAXIMUMTOUCHES` returns the
>   aggregate maximum of the maximum
>   number of contacts supported by every
>   digitizer in the system. If the system
>   has only single-touch digitizers, the
>   return value is `1`. If the system has
>   multi-touch digitizers, the return
>   value is the number of simultaneous
>   contacts the hardware can provide.

Comment: Here's how to use GetSystemMetrics in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725781/getsystemmetrics-returns-different-results-for-net-4-5-net-4-0