# GetSystemMetrics() returns different results for .NET 4.5 & .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, getsystemmetrics

During a .NET 4.0 -> .NET 4.5 application migration process I've discovered an extremely strange behavior. I've been able to track this issue down to this short code snippet:

```
class Program
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int CXFRAME = 0x20;
        const int CYFRAME = 0x21;

        var dx = GetSystemMetrics(CXFRAME);
        var dy = GetSystemMetrics(CYFRAME);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}x{1}", dx, dy);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When compiled with `Target Framework = 4.0` (and also 2.0, 3.0, 3.5), it outputs `8x8`

When compiled with `Target Framework = 4.5`, it outputs `4x4`

Running this sample with MSVS2012 debugger also always outputs `4x4` (with *any* target framework).

Other options (target framework profile, target platform, enabling/disabling Aero) do not affect the result, the only things that change the output are target framework and running with debugger. I've been able to reproduce this issue on 3 computers, unfortunately they are almost identical in terms of installed software:

- Windows 7 Ultmate SP1 (russian, all updates installed) with MSVS2012 (english/rusian) Update 1
- Windows 8 (on virtual machine)

Currently I'm thinking about patching some .NET classes (`SystemParameters` for example), which call `GetSystemMetrics()` using reflection, but I'm not sure how to get correct metric values.

Questions:

- Am I missing something? How can `GetSystemMetrics()` be affected by target framework?
- Is there any way to call `GetSystemMetrics()` from .NET 4.5 app and get correct results?

I'm open to any suggestions on fixing this issue. Also, if you cannot reproduce the issue, please leave a short system description in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Microsoft, this is by-design.

See here for full details:

- [The SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness seems to return incorrect value - Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763767/the-systemparameters-windowresizeborderthickness-seems-to-return-incorrect-value) (no archived version available)
- [Regression: ::GetSystemMetrics delivers different values - Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753224/regression-getsystemmetrics-delivers-different-values) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20141223024016/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753224/regression-getsystemmetrics-delivers-different-values))

Despite MS saying it's "by design", I still think it's a bug!

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything.

Comment: Too bad those links are down. I wonder if anyone still has the explanation given there.

Answer (score 6):

So, it's actually a by-design behavior, and if someone has similar issues, here is the code which always outputs the same result:

```
const int CXFRAME = 0x20;
const int CYFRAME = 0x21;
const int CXPADDEDBORDER = 92;

var dx = GetSystemMetrics(CXFRAME);
var dy = GetSystemMetrics(CYFRAME);
var d  = GetSystemMetrics(CXPADDEDBORDER);
dx += d;
dy += d;

Console.WriteLine("{0}x{1}", dx, dy);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Also note that `RibbonWindow` WPF control, which uses `WindowChrome` and now comes as a part of .NET 4.5 does not know about this changes and displays messy window borders (fortunately, I think it can be fixed using modified styles).

Comment: Very helpful note, thank you. Initially it was not by-design, it was confirmed to be a windows bug. Regarding  `WindowsChrome` problem, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61299269/1943849, which can help if you're trying to fix maximized window.