# How to figure out in C# whether a system is touch supported or not

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-8, touch

How to know(in C#) whether a device is touch enabled or not on Windows 7 and Windows 8. Using the GetSystemMetrics API doesn't always work correctly. Is there some other way to know the touch capability, the number of contacts a digitizer can provide.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/5957796/1341464

Answer (score 0):

you can check out this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There is the `GetSystemMetrics`  where you can get the `SM_MAXIMUMTOUCHES`. When its > 0 there is a digitizes, otherwise its 0.

> Nonzero if there are digitizers in the system; otherwise, 0.
>   SM_MAXIMUMTOUCHES returns the aggregate maximum of the maximum number of contacts supported by every digitizer in the system. If the system has only single-touch digitizers, the return value is 1. If the system has multi-touch digitizers, the return value is the number of simultaneous contacts the hardware can provide.
>   Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, and Windows XP/2000:  This value is not supported.

Comment: I already tried this out. But not of use in my particular scenario.
Is there any other way we can sort this out. Also i need to know if touch is supported via USB in a particular system